# Как получить младшие 8 бит числа?

Tags: java

Есть число типа `int <= 65545`. Необходимо получить младшие и старшие 8 бит. Со "старшими 8-ю битами разобрался, достаточно сдвинуть вправо с заполнением нулями (`>>>8`). А вот с младшими никак не пойму.

*старшие*   *младшие*

|-----------||-----------|

`1111111100000000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно обнулить старшие биты

```
int a = 0x1234;
int bigA = a >>> 8;
int lowA = a & 0xff;
```